# Why I am unable to take integer input starting with zero?

Tags: c, input, integer, scanf, zero

I am trying to take integer input in c using the `scanf` function.

When I give the input as 5 it prints 5 but when the input is 05 it is omitting the 0 and prints 5.

Can someone please help me, I don't understand what is wrong.

```
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d",n);    
}
```

My input was `05`

Excepted output is `05`
Actual output is `5`

Comment: `05` = `5` for numbers. Since your input and output are integers and not strings, it is as expected.

Comment: What makes you think that `5` is different from `05` or from `005` ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky This? `printf("%d %d", 10, 010);`

Comment: @Lundin for you, but probably not for the OP

Comment: @AlexLop.  Correction... 05 `==` 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `5` as int type is same is `05` as int.
2. If you want to print digits in format "05" or "020" i.e. with a leading zero, use

   `printf("%02d",var);// for 1 digit variable with one leading zero`

   `printf("%03d",var);// for 2 digit variable with one leading zero,for 1 digit variable with two leading zero`

   `printf("%04d",var);// for 2 digit variable with two leading zeros,for 1 digit variable with three leading zeros`

   and so on. Increment value before `d` if you want more leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

"5", "05", and "five" are three different *representations* for the same integer. When you take integer input, you get an integer as your input. If you want a string representation of an integer as your input, don't read into an integer. Read into a buffer that can hold a string of characters.